# Selecting the Last Direct Child

Tags: css

I am trying to select the last direct child of a set of elements, as in, the last .container in:

[image]

The problem is that it just isn't applying the styling. Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
#allthecontent  > .container:last-child {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't exactly work like that. Your selector would match an element with `container` class, which happens to be the last child of its parent.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry, was being stupid.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not possible to match the last occurrence of `.container` unless it happens to be the last child of its parent, you can use the nth-last-child selector to specify a range.

```
#allthecontent > ​.container:nth-last-child(-n + 2) {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
}
```

This would match any element with a `container` class that appears within the last 2 elements of the parent. This selector doesn't work in IE8 and below, though.